# Mysql - Getting latest contents from 3 different table

Tags: mysql

i have 3 `mysql` table as like these:

```
a) books -> id, name, price, date

b) audio -> id, name, price, date

c) parfume -> id, name, price, date
```

*note: all date's are `php` `time()` format.*

now; can i get the latest added 10 record from mix of them by their `date` value?

for example:

```
1- hobbit book -> 10.10.2013 09:10

2-  metallica cd -> 10.10.2013 06:10

3-  dostoyevski book -> 10.09.2013 15:00

4-  armani parfume -> 10.09.2013 10:00

5-  madonna cd -> 10.08.2013 16:00

6-  ....
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please improve your question, also show the query that you have created.

Comment: The table contains strings for dates, not datetimes? Also, `latest added 10 record from mix of them by their date value` may need to be clarified, preferably by sample data and a sample desired result.

Comment: "can i get the latest added 10 record from mix of them by their date value" can you specify how you are mixing tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select * from (select * from books 
           union 
           select * from audio 
           union 
           select * from parfume )
  order by date desc limit 10
```

Comment: thnks frnd, u need to increase the rating also ,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you convert the date columns in MySql so that the `order by` clause returns the result in proper order.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT  id, name, price, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r') FROM books
   union
   SELECT  id, name, price, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r') FROM audio
   union
   SELECT  id, name, price, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %r') FROM parfume
) as T1
ORDER BY T1.date desc
LIMIT 10
```